# Streams on different thread read write keep alive

Tags: c#, .net

I have a server that listens my messages, and from 15 to 15 seconds it's sending a keep alive message.
I need to implement a client that sends messages to the server and listens continuously .
I am using streams writer and reader on different threads.
The problem is that I need to write different messages and listen to the respective responses , and behind that I need to send that keep alive message. If not the remote host aborts the connection.

```
public static void main(){
    Connect(tcpClient1,port1,stream1);
    connectDone.WaitOne();

    Connect(tcpClient2, port1,stream2);
    connectDone.WaitOne();

    Connect(tcpClient3,port1,stream1);
    connectDone.WaitOne();

    writeThread = new Thread(() => Send(tcpClient1,stream1));

    writeThread.Start();

    sendDone.WaitOne();

    readThread = new Thread(() => Read(tcpClient2,stream2));

    readThread.Start();

    receiveDone.WaitOne();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void Send(TcpClient tcpClient,NetworkStream stream)
{
        try
        {
            stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            int i, j = 0;              
            while (tcpClient.Connected)
            {

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

                Console.WriteLine("Write your index for the message:");

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter the Integer Number : ");
                    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer value!");
                }

                if (stream.CanWrite)
                {
                    lock (stream)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

                        sw.WriteLineAsync(DPLHeader(Messages.ElementAt(i)));

                        sw.Flush();

                        Thread.Sleep(23000);
                        sendDone.Set();

                        Console.WriteLine("Sent to server the message.");
                    }

                }
                j++;
        }
  }

  public static void Read(TcpClient tcpClient, NetworkStream stream)
  {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            // stream.ReadTimeout = 100;

            while (tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                /*if (i != 0)
                {
                    receiveDone.Reset();
                }*/

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);


                if (stream.CanRead && stream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    lock (stream)
                    {
                        while (sr.Peek() > -1)
                        {

                            response = sr.ReadLine();
                        }

                        receiveDone.Set();
                        Console.WriteLine("Received..." + response);

                        List<string> list = Decode(DecodingMsg(response));
                        SendToText(list);
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400296/c-sharp-sending-and-receiving-a-tcp-ip-message-to-an-ip-address-and-port#17400356 its about using TCPListener on "server" side.

Comment: Actually the server is a device and I can't change his behaivor . All I can do is on the "client" side. If I understood good what you meant.

Comment: Ok, so you send a message, receive the answer, then send another, ... if its only one device, why using threads?

Comment: So I can read and write continuously and simultaneously